# encrypt data in Javascript with "RSACryptoServiceProvider" Public Key -> Exceed Maximum Exception

Tags: javascript, c#, encryption, cryptography

I have a Instance of the "RSACryptoServiceProvider" in my backend Code.

```
  oRsa = new System.Security.Cryptography.RSACryptoServiceProvider(2048);
  var Key = CryptoHelper.ExportPublicKey(oRsa);
```

The Code to Export the Public Key I got from here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/28407693/579623 ( I also tried this https://stackoverflow.com/a/25591659/579623)

the "key" is send to my Javascript Client wich uses JSEncrypt to encrypt the Data.

Problem now is I got the following error in my Backend: "The data to be decrypted exceeds the maximum for this modulus of 256 bytes."

Comment: Can System.Security.Cryptography.RSACryptoServiceProvider use a key size greater than 256?

Comment: A 2048 bit key can be used to encrypt a max of 245 bytes, if the encryption works presumably your length is less than this, how is the data received by the back end? as base64/hex string? Are you transforming this back into a byte[] correctly?

Comment: Does JSEncrypt.encrypt returen something base64 encoded? I thought these are the encrypted bytes?

Comment: I looked and yes it returns Base64 so you need to convert that to a byte array for decryption

Comment: So the question becomes to Jochen: did you decode the data before decrypting it? If not then Alex may have answered your question

Comment: I now tried to use atob(xx) of the encrypted data, before I send it over the websocket! But I still get the same error on the backend!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finaly got it to working using Code from : http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/22073/Object-Oriented-JavaScript-Class-Library-in-C-NET
it was sugested here: [RSA: Encrypt password in javascript but failed to decrypt that in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19418021/rsa-encrypt-password-in-javascript-but-failed-to-decrypt-that-in-c-sharp)